# Can I get the underlying conneciton and transaction objects from NHibernate?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

Is it possible to get the `DbConnection` and `DbTransaction` objects from a NHibernate transaction?

I need to combine some NHibernate calls with a third-part library inside the same transaction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ISession.Connection` returns the `IDBConnection` object. For the transaction see the blog post below.

```
    //http://ayende.com/blog/1583/i-hate-this-code

    private static IDbTransaction GetTransaction(ISession session)

    {
        using (var command = session.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            session.Transaction.Enlist(command);
            return command.Transaction;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can start transaction inside of an NHibernate session, and easily get an access to `DbConnection` *(could be casted even to SQL or Oracle one - if that makes sense)*. Then do the stuff with it and apply final commit/rollback:

```
var session = ... // get an NHiberante ISession
var transaction = session.BeginTransaction();

var conn = session.Connection;
var dbConnection = conn as System.Data.Common.DbConnection;

// do the stuff with DbConnection

transaction.Commit();
// or
transaction.Rollback();
```

Comment: What about getting access to the DbTransaction object?

Comment: transaction is shared for your connection.. so you can create one in session or later on your DbConnection.. it is in fact still the same transaction.. hope that helps ;)

Comment: Hmm. Now I'm wondering why DbCommand even has a Transaction property in the first place.

Comment: Why not? where is the problem? You can start your transaction somewhere and share just a connection. Later, by touching the Transaction property you can Commit/Rollback your stuff. And that will be a statement effecting all the statements ... issued after transaction creation. And as I said.. it could be created on a session or db conneciton.. because in fact.. below it is the same. Its more about  understanding basic ADO.NET then an issue with NHiberante and 3d party connection re-use... hope it's getting more clear ;) ;)